# Timestamp Index Collection Search

Tags: pandas

For a time series with timestamp as index:

```
df
    time    price
    1571875201500    7450.5
    1571875201776    7467.5
    1571875201777    7467.5
    1571875232018    7465.5
    1571875232019    7465.5
    1571875239995    7465.0
```

how should I search with a custom lookback interval? 
For example, if I select `df[df['price'] == 7465.5]` to get

```
    time    price
    1571875232018    7465.5
    1571875232019    7465.5
```

for each row I want to collect all rows that are within 300 milliseconds before. The expected output is:

```
df
    time    price
    1571875201776    7467.5
    1571875201777    7467.5
    1571875232018    7465.5
    1571875232019    7465.5
```